# Can you help explain static lifetime in hyper in rust?

Tags: rust, hyper

I am using hyper and I am confuse with some codes.

My code is like

```
 self.hyper_client = ...

 match Request::builder()
        .method(Method::POST)
        .uri(uri)
        .header("content-type", "application/json")
        .body(Body::from(serde_json::to_string(&content).unwrap()))
    {
        Ok(req) => {
            match self.hyper_client.request(req).await
        },
        Err(err) => {
            ...
        }
    }
```

First I think the `req` object generated by `Request::builder` is not static lifetime right?

But in `client.request` function, the prototype is `pub fn request(&self, mut req: Request<B>) -> ResponseFuture` and Client's `B` is

```
impl<C, B> Client<C, B>
where
    C: Connect + Clone + Send + Sync + 'static,
    B: HttpBody + Send + 'static,
    B::Data: Send,
    B::Error: Into<Box<dyn StdError + Send + Sync>>,
{
....
```

it seems `B` should be static?

I am confused about static lifetime, can you help me about it?

Thanks.

Comment: Owned values have a `'static` lifetime. This is because they can be made to outlive any other lifetime by moving them as needed.

Comment: @BallpointBen there is a slight difference between having a `'static` lifetime and being bound by it, owned values are the latter, **not** the former. It is a [common misconception about lifetimes though](https://github.com/pretzelhammer/rust-blog/blob/master/posts/common-rust-lifetime-misconceptions.md#2-if-t-static-then-t-must-be-valid-for-the-entire-program)